# Steamworks SDK achievement de-synchronization

Tags: steam, achievements

The development of my game is coming to an end and I'm now looking into getting a hold of a publisher and publishing my game to Steam. To do this I'm also preparing my game for the use of the [Steamworks SDK](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/sdk) that handles general Steam business like achievements among other things.

The thing is my game already has a built-in achievement system and I'm worried that my achievement system and the Steam achievement system might get de-synchronized for one reason or another - as in the achievement is unlocked locally in the built-in system but not unlocked in the Steam API. This seems to have happened to several users ([Plants vs Zombies example](https://steamcommunity.com/app/3590/discussions/0/648812917624877343/)) and Steam has made it clear that this is the developer's responsibility.

**How should I be a responsible developer and prevent de-synchronization or deal with it if it occurs?**